In Japan, is it legal to deny service to someone if they're a foreigner?
In America, it is generally not legal for e.g. a restaurant to deny someone service based on their nationality. However, in Japan, is it legal for a bar or restaurant to deny service to people solely because they are foreigners? I've heard stories of this happening several times, but have never heard stories of legal backlash against it.
Edit: language wasn't part of my question. The incidents I heard of were from people who speak Japanese with decent proficiency, but were still denied service. That being said, I'd also like to hear the answer for the case where a foreigner doesn't speak Japanese.

There's at least some reports of (almost certainly local only) restaurants up-charging tourists/foreigners, which would also be illegal in the US....

@Clockwork-Muse Citation needed. There's laws against discrimination based on national origin but not nationality/citizenship. In fact, the greatest disparity will be in state-run public universities: the majority of slots are reserved for residents, most of the time non-citizens cannot gain residency at all, resulting in fees easily $100k more over the course of a degree.
